# How to disable WLTrusteerInternal.init in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any configuration or way to disable MFP's **WLTrusteerInternal.init()** routine?

I have an adroid app on MFP 7.1. I wanted to use the phone_gap plugin to write my trusteer code instead of MFP's WLTrusteerInternal class for flexibility. However, it seems that MFP tries to automatically initialize the SDK everytime it finds the Trusteer SDK in the Lib folder.

```
07-28 23:25:13.201 24643-24643/com.sampleapp D/ResourcesManager: creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.sampleapp-2/base.apk
07-28 23:25:13.421 24643-24671/com.sampleapp W/WLClient: WLClient.createInstance in WLClient.java:225 :: You should pass a context that is assignable from the Activity class. WLClient instance may be used to start an activity.
07-28 23:25:13.801 24643-24671/com.sampleapp I/com.worklight.common.WLTrusteer: WLTrusteer.checkTrusteerSDK in WLTrusteer.java:127 :: Trusteer SDK found.
07-28 23:25:13.821 24643-24643/com.sampleapp I/TAZ: libtaz for arm
07-28 23:25:13.911 24643-24643/com.sampleapp I/TAZ: [INFO ] Creating TSSVM sigfile header
07-28 23:25:13.911 24643-24643/com.sampleapp I/TAZ: [INFO ] Creating TSSVM sigfile header
07-28 23:25:13.911 24643-24643/com.sampleapp I/TAZ: [INFO ] Creating TSSVM sigfile header
07-28 23:25:13.921 24643-24643/com.sampleapp I/TAZ: [INFO ] Creating TSSVM sigfile header
07-28 23:25:13.921 24643-24643/com.sampleapp I/TAZ: [INFO ] TAS Version <4.1.31>
07-28 23:25:13.921 24643-24671/com.sampleapp E/com.worklight.common.internal.WLTrusteerInternal: WLTrusteerInternal.init in WLTrusteerInternal.java:61 :: TasInitialize() failed. Invalid or missing license.
07-28 23:25:13.931 24643-24671/com.sampleapp D/wl.splashscreen: WLSplashScreen.show in WLSplashScreen.java:64 :: Showing Splash Screen
```

I have tried to comment out the Trusteer plugin from *android/native/res/xml/**config.xml*** but it still tried to initialize trusteer.

```
<!--<feature name="WLTrusteer">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLTrusteerPlugin" />
</feature> -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible. the Trusteer initialization is built-into the MobileFirst client framework init code.

You can open a feature request to change this behavior: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/help/

Note however that in the recently released MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 you now have the freedom to do whatever you want. Learn more about v8.0: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com